# is it possible to update live activity view after performing LiveactivityIntent action?

Tags: ios, swiftui, wwdc, widgetliveactivity

I need to update the live activity's view (like updating the text or remove and add buttons) after performing the intent action. For widget we have timeline mechanism to reload the UI. In apple document they mentioned that Liveactivity follows same life cycle as widget.

> Live Activities don’t use a timeline mechanism to update their content. However, they use WidgetKit and a widget extension with a similar cycle of view archiving and decoding.

Not able to find a method to update live activities UI.

Comment: did yo find any solution to this?

Comment: yes bro, you have to share the intent file with main target

Comment: how to share intent file with main target? I need to udate liveactivvity from within widget.

Comment: first select the file in which AppIntent is extended. Then select the inspector from top right corner. There you have to select first option(file inspector).  There you can find  `Target membership` section.  In that section you have to select the main target.

Comment: @iroh Is it possible to share a sample code for having custom button with AppIntent. I'm implementing a button action but build getting failed with error and not able to adopt to LiveActivityIntent protocol.

Comment: hi @Logunath, kindly check the git repo given below. If you have any query kindly ping me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Kindly refer the following git project https://github.com/praveeniroh/LiveActivity/tree/main/LiveActivity

Note: we can update and end live activity without opening our app.

Points to remember:

1. The LiveActivityIntent file must be shared with both main target and widget target
2. You have to provide specific UI while updating state